# R Reticulate: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: r, pandas, r-package, reticulate

I am using the Azure ML Notebook with `R` kernel to use a python script through `reticulate` package but I am unable to install `pandas` library which is using in the python script. I am following the instructions from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html). I have written the following `R` code:

```
library(reticulate)
Sys.which("python")
use_python("/usr/bin/python3.8")
```

When I use `py_config()` then it gives me the following output:

```
python:         /usr/bin/python3.8
libpython:      /usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so
pythonhome:     //usr://usr
version:        3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)  [GCC 9.4.0]
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
```

Now, `conda_list()` shows the `r-reticulate` environment and its location as `/anaconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python` and when I try to install `pandas` in default `r-reticulate` environment using:

```
conda_install("r-reticulate", "pandas")
```

Then it gives the following output:

```
+ '/anaconda/bin/conda' 'install' '--yes' '--name' 'r-reticulate' '-c' 'conda-forge' 'pandas'
```

But when I use `pandas <- import("pandas")` then it gives me the following error message:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Can anyone please tell me whether this is issue related to path or something else and how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is, but have you tried

```
reticulate::py_install('pandas', pip = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, tried it and getting the following error: Warning message in system2(python, c("-c", shQuote(command)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE):
“running command ''/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1' had status 1”
Error in if (idx != -1) version <- substring(version, 1, idx - 1): the condition has length > 1 Could you please help ?

Comment: no idea what the error message is supposed to convey.... does pip = TRUE cause the error?

Comment: Yes, getting the error message as mentioned in above comment after running `reticulate::py_install('pandas', pip = TRUE)`

Comment: I meant have you run it with reticulate::py_install('pandas', pip = FALSE) I would guess it is some kind of version conflict...

Comment: After running `reticulate::py_install('pandas', pip = FALSE)`, I am getting the same error message. It might be version conflict but I guess pandas is installed in a wrong location because `conda_install("r-reticulate", "pandas")` is working fine.